# I get a invalid column name exception while accessing a Entity field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, foreign-keys

I have recently added a column named 'CreatedBy'in the Course table which reference the UserID in the user table in the database and created a corresponding entity field for it. But while accessing the CreatedBy field I get a error: 
**System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'CreatedByID'.**

I tried different means of data annotations but it did not work.

**Entities:**

```
public partial class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.CourseLessons = new List<CourseLesson>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string CourseDescription { get; set; }        
    public int? CreatedByID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedByID")]
    public virtual WebsiteUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CourseLesson> CourseLessons { get; set; }
}

public partial class WebsiteUser
{
    public WebsiteUser()
    {
        // Other code
    }
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult EditCourse()
{
    SQLContext context = new SQLContext();
    var deletethis = context.Courses.First().CreatedBy;  // Gives error
    return View(context.Courses);
}
```

Comment: what Is your entity type? Database First or Code first?
did you update your database and migration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"CreatedByID" is the default conventional name for the database table column corresponding to the `CreatedByID` property which you mapped as a foreign key here

```
public int? CreatedByID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("CreatedByID")]
public virtual WebsiteUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

In order to change the conventional column name you could use the `[Column]` data annotation (attribute):

```
[Column("CreatedBy")]
public int? CreatedByID { get; set; }
```

or fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
    .Property(e => e.CreatedById)
    .HasColumnName("CreatedBy");
```

To recap, `ForeignKey` attribute specifies the name of the *entity property* to be mapped as FK column, while `Column` attribute specifies the name of the *table column* mapped to that property.

Answer (score -3):

Try to use single quote

> '

instead double quote

> "

it worked for me in Postgresql database.

For example

```
[ForeignKey('CreatedByID')]
```

Comment: Why try that? Did you try it?

Comment: If you tried it, you would not ask someone else to try it.

Comment: Did this even compile for you? I guess if it didn't compile, then you did not get to the runtime exception part either, hence problem solved in a sense?